# How do I reach the conclusion that the curve shape of this equation leans to the left/right before/after $n=2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$$a^n+(x^2+y^2)^{n/2}+b=((x-a)^2+y^2)^{n/2}$$
where a and b are positive constants and $1<n \le 7$.

Using GeoGebra [one can see](https://www.geogebra.org/suite/sxfa8ge6) when $1<n<2$ the curve is leaning to the left; when $n=2$ the curve becomes a straight line in a form of $x=K$ which is derivable with hand calculation; when $n>2$ the curve is leaning to the right.

**My main question is:**

1. "How do I reach the conclusion that the curve shape of this equation leans to the left/right before/after $n=2$? How can I prove this?"

Some more questions are:

2. "How do I prove that the curve keeps the same shape for all $1<n<2$ or $n>2$?"
3. "For $n \le 1$, the curve disappears. Why is that?"

My questions originate from [this journal's relay region computation equation](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/779917).

Comment: Note that when $n=2$ exactly, there's lots of cancellation and the equation simplifies to just $0=-2ax$, or $x=0$.

Comment: To give a mathematical answer, we need to ask a specific mathematical question. What is it about the "shape" that you want to investigate? For example, the fact that the graph is to the left of the $y$-axis for $1<n<2$ but to the right of the $y$-axis for $n>2$? Something about the curvature of the graph? ...

Comment: @GregMartin Sorry for the confusion. I edited the question about its leaning characteristic to the left/right for certain values of n. And yes it does simplify when $n=2$. The equation simplifies to $x=-b/{2a}$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to your question, but I have had fun playing with Geogebra and can see why the answer you want isn't easily answered.

I opened a 3D graphics page (Geogebra Classic 5) and entered three equations:
z=LHS of your equation
z=RHS
and your equation.

This is the result for $a=1$, $b=2$, $n=3$ (entered as slider controls):
[image]
Your equation gives a projection of the intersection of the two 3D surfaces onto the $x-y$ plane.

As $n$ decreases the shape of the surfaces change so that at $n=1$ they become two cones with the same apex angle. Hence no intersection.

Interestingly, if $n$ is allowed to go below zero, the surfaces intersect again, but now the equation produces a closed shape. (Depending on $a$ and $b$ it doesn't appear until somewhere near $n=-1$ but I suspect that's due to resolution issues in Geogebra and/or the screen)